# show images sd card specific folder in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-gridview, android-bitmap

I try to show images sd card specific folder.I wrote some code and i can show all images in my divice in Gridview.This is my source code

```
 private void fetchGalleryImages() {
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};//get all columns of type images
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;//order data by date
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy + " DESC");

    galleryImageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();//Init array



    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);//get column index
        galleryImageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));//get Image from column index
        System.out.println("Array path" + galleryImageUrls.get(i));
    }


}
```

how i can wrote my code to can show images only sdcard/myfolder/ (only myfolder images)? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the image from specific file use select and select arg like this
for you it will be `Image` in place of `Audio`

```
 String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=?";

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{""+file_uri};
```

And here `file_uri` is of string type just declare a string named `file_uri=your file name` .

So your code will be like this

```
 MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, selection,
        selectionArgs, orderBy + " DESC");
```

Comment: what is a id if my folder name is myfolder?

Comment: where use selection string ? can you show me full source?

Comment: in your code you are declaring it as null value the 1 null